# sort an array of UTF-8 strings alphabetically, ignoring accents / diacritics

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, joomla

I don't have enough knowledge about character encoding. I use `utf-8` I think. I have an array and I want to have it in alphabetical and case sensitive order.

I am doing that but I used some strings in an array, and some of them start with `ç,ı,ö,ğ` and they went to the end of the sorted array.

I want the sorting like `abcç gğ oö ıi sş`. I use it in Joomla and if `JArrayHelper::sortObjects` works for it, how do I use it? I don't understand what I should do for the second parameter. Thanks for reading.

Comment: what is the code inside JArrayHelper::sortObjects() function? maybe you should copy that code in a new function and adapt it to suit your needs?

Comment: here is the likn of JArrayHelper class's and methods and paramteres. I couldnt solve the question yet – http://api.joomla.org/11.4/Joomla-Platform/Utilities/JArrayHelper.html#sortObjects

Answer (score 0):

```
php> $foo = array("ç", "öooo", "öaaa");
php> sort($foo);
php> print_r($foo);

Array
(
    [0] => ç
    [1] => öaaa
    [2] => öooo
)
```

Comment: All this shows is that sort() considers ö to be equal to ö. The OP was asking for a sort function that puts ö after o, and both of them between n and p.

Comment: I checked, and php's sort() does exactly what the OP was describing: words beginning with diacritical characters go to the end of the sorted array.